# Helm template - combine yamls with .Files.Get

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am using the tp function, https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function
to include a config file of yaml inside a template.

```
templates/omer.yaml: 
{{ $omer := tpl (.Files.Get "files/app.conf") . }}
{{- $omer-}}
```

The file files/app.conf contains:

```
pod1:
  custom:
    deployment:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/proxyCPU: 10m
        sidecar.istio.io/proxyMemory: "16Mi"
        sidecar.istio.io/proxyCPULimit: 50m
        sidecar.istio.io/proxyMemoryLimit: "64Mi"
```

When I helm template, it works fine. What I'm trying to accomplish, is to merge the app.conf yaml to another yaml, also defined in the templates folder. Trying the merge command for other yamls is working, but when using the tpl Files.Get it is recognised as a string and not as template, trying templates/omer.yaml:

```
{{ $omer := tpl (.Files.Get "files/app.conf") . }}
{{- $output := mergeOverwrite $omer }}
{{- $output -}}
```

gives me an error:
Error: template: chart/templates/omer.yaml:2:30: executing "chart/templates/omer.yaml" at <$omer>: wrong type for value; expected map[string]interface {}; got string

Also when trying to convert:

```
{{- $output := fromYaml ($omer ) }}
```

Getting an error:
Error: YAML parse error on chart/templates/omer.yaml: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type releaseutil.SimpleHead

Comment: You do need `fromYaml` as `tpl` processes the content from the file, loaded as string, into another string, but `mergeOverride` needs that string to be parsed as YAML. The error you get with your last piece of code seems to happen *after* template processing and is not related to `fromYaml`. Theoretically, `{{$omer := fromYaml (tpl (.Files.Get "files/app.conf") .) }}` should do the trick but if you get a similar error, you need to provide the whole file so that we can reproduce it.